# How to minify MobileFirst hybrid iOS project?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, minify

I would like to obfuscate my code. [The tutorial is under Concatenation and minification topic](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-to-create-build-and-manage-mobilefirst-project-artifacts/#creatingHybridApps)

These are the steps I’ve used to minify the code in hybrid app:

1. export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
2. cd /Users/keatooon/Desktop/testmfpminify2
3. mfp create testProject
4. cd testProject
5. mfp add hybrid testApp
6. mfp start
7. mfp build
8. mfp push
9. mfp console
10. mfp push —concatenate —minify

> xxx:testProject xxx$ mfp push --concatenate --minify
>
> Preparing for push...
>
> Verifying Server Configuration...
>
> Runtime 'testProject' will be used to push the project into.
>
> Pushing to Server...
>
> Deploying
>   /Users/xxx/Desktop/wktestmfp2/testProject/bin/testApp-common.wlapp...
>
> Deploy complete for
>   /Users/xxx/Desktop/wktestmfp2/testProject/bin/testApp-common.wlapp.
>
> /Users/xxx/Desktop/wktestmfp2/testProject/bin/testApp-common.wlapp
>   has been deployed.
>
> Push Completed Successfully.

However, it does not add any security to the code.

Code before vs after Concatenation and minification:

[image]
[image]

Moreover, the code doesn’t work at all after concatenating and minifying it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying which files you want to minify, done in the build-settings.xml file located in the root folder of your application, nothing would actually get concatenated and/or minified.

The fact that it fails the app from running is interesting...

Have you edited said file? If not, try to.
Find more information about concatenation and minification, here:

- Updating the build-settings.xml file: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_optimize_app_cli.html
- Configuring the build-settings.xml file: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.reference.doc/cli_commands/build_config.html

Comment: Hi @Idan Adar, thx for your help. I'm able to minify and obfuscate the code. However it's only doing "google closure compiler simple optimizations", i would like to use the advanced feature. How should I go about it? Does IBM Mobile First support this feature?

Comment: The options that is written about in the docs are the only supported options. You can of course choose to not use this feature and implement it on your own using available tools online.

Comment: Thx for replying... I think we need a much more advanced code obfuscation tool. Relying solely on the supported options will not be sufficient. Aiks...